# POST Request in Ruby/Python returning 'No Data'

Tags: python, ruby, post, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to make a POST request via either Ruby or Python for a form on the following website:
http://diamond-cut.com.au/holloway_cut_adviser.htm

The request returns 'No Data.' I think I'm omitting something from my request headers (e.g., user-agent, accept. Including these parameters has not changed the outcome)

Minimal code that is returning 'No Data' in Ruby:

```
require 'restclient'
url='http://www.pricescope.com/hca.php'
params = {"depth_textbox" => '60',
          "table_textbox" => '57',
          "crown_listbox" => "0",
          "crown_textbox" => '34',
          "pavilion_listbox" => "0",
          "pavilion_textbox" => '40.5',
          "cutlet_textbox" => "0"}

page=RestClient.post(url,params)
```

In Python:

```
import requests
url='http://www.pricescope.com/hca.php'
params = {"depth_textbox" : '60',
          "table_textbox" : '57',
          "crown_listbox" : "0",
          "crown_textbox" : '34',
          "pavilion_listbox" : "0",
          "pavilion_textbox" : '40.5',
          "cutlet_textbox" : "0"}
r=requests.post(url,params)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to play with headers a little:

```
headers = {'Referer': 'http://www.pricescope.com/hca.php'}

r = requests.post(url, data=params, headers=headers)
print r.content
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. For completeness, here's the equivalent fix in Ruby: `page=RestClient.post(url,data=params,headers={'Referer'=>url})` Is there an intuitive explanation for why the Referer header was needed? Also, how would debugging reveal this?

Comment: @GolanTrevize it is restrictions from site owners.

Answer (score -1):

In your python code, it should be as follows.

> r=requests.post(url,data=params)

This [links](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) also could help you to understand the POST syntax.